# I am trying to define a dictionary in which Name, Port No, Manufacture's part number, Serial No, Product Id are to be fetched from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

server side response : ['fc1/1 sfp is present', '    Name is CISCO-FINISAR', "    Manufacturer's part number is FTLF8524P2BNL-C2", '    Revision is D', '    Serial number is FNS190500CN', '    Nominal bit rate is 4300 Mb/s', '    FC Transmitter type is short wave laser w/o OFC (SN)', '    FC Transmitter supports intermediate distance link length', '    Transmission medium is multimode laser with 62.5 um aperture (M6)', '    Supported speeds are - Min speed: 1000 Mb/s, Max speed: 4000 Mb/s', '    Cisco extended id is unknown (0x0)', '    Cisco part number is 10-2195-01', '    Cisco pid is DS-SFP-FC4G-SW', '', '    No tx fault, no rx loss, in sync state, diagnostic monitoring type is 0x68', '    SFP Diagnostics Information:', '       Temperature           :  29.90 C    ', '        Voltage               :   3.29 V       ', '        Current               :   9.15 mA         ', '        Optical Tx Power      :  -4.06 dBm        ', '        Optical Rx Power      :  -2.53 dBm        ', '        Tx Fault count  : 0', '    Note: ++  high-alarm; +  high-warning; --  low-alarm; -low-warning', '', 'fc1/2 sfp is present', '    Name is CISCO-AVAGO', "    Manufacturer's part number is SFBR-5780AMZ-CS1", '    Revision is G4.1', '    Serial number is AVD1745B4WL', '    Nominal bit rate is 8500 Mb/s', '    Link length supported for 50/125um OM2 fiber is 50 m', '    Link length supported for 62.5/125um fiber is 21 m', '    Link length supported for 50/125um OM3 fiber is 150 m', '    FC Transmitter type is short wave laser w/o OFC (SN)', '    FC Transmitter supports short distance link length', '    Transmission medium is multimode laser with 62.5 um aperture (M6)', '    Supported speeds are - Min speed: 2000 Mb/s, Max speed: 8000 Mb/s', '    Cisco extended id is unknown (0x0)', '    Cisco part number is 10-2418-01', '    Cisco pid is DS-SFP-FC8G-SW', '', '    No tx fault, no rx loss, in sync state, diagnostic monitoring type is 0x68', '    SFP Diagnostics Information:', '       Temperature           :  34.16 C    ', '        Voltage               :   3.30 V       ', '        Current               :   6.20 mA         ', '        Optical Tx Power      :  -2.51 dBm        ', '        Optical Rx Power      :  -4.41 dBm        ', '        Tx Fault count  : 0', '    Note: ++  high-alarm; +  high-warning; --  low-alarm; -low-warning', '', 'fc1/3 sfp is present', '    Name is CISCO-FINISAR', "    Manufacturer's part number is FTLF8524P2BNL-C2", '    Revision is D', '    Serial number is FNS190506K6', '    Nominal bit rate is 4300 Mb/s', '    FC Transmitter type is short wave laser w/o OFC (SN)', '    FC Transmitter supports intermediate distance link length', '    Transmission medium is multimode laser with 62.5 um aperture (M6)', '    Supported speeds are - Min speed: 1000 Mb/s, Max speed: 4000 Mb/s', '    Cisco extended id is unknown (0x0)', '    Cisco part number is 10-2195-01', '    Cisco pid is DS-SFP-FC4G-SW', '', '    No tx fault, no rx loss, in sync state, diagnostic monitoring type is 0x68', '    SFP Diagnostics Information:', '       Temperature           :  29.58 C    ', '        Voltage               :   3.29 V       ', '        Current               :   6.79 mA         ', '        Optical Tx Power      :  -4.03 dBm        ', '        Optical Rx Power      :  -2.52 dBm        ', '        Tx Fault count  : 0', '    Note: ++  high-alarm; +  high-warning; --  low-alarm; -low-warning', '', 'fc1/4 sfp is present', '    Name is CISCO-FINISAR', "    Manufacturer's part number is FTLF8524P2BNL-C2", '    Revision is D', '    Serial number is FNS19050AWE', '    Nominal bit rate is 4300 Mb/s', '    FC Transmitter type is short wave laser w/o OFC (SN)', '    FC Transmitter supports intermediate distance link length', '    Transmission medium is multimode laser with 62.5 um aperture (M6)', '    Supported speeds are - Min speed: 1000 Mb/s, Max speed: 4000 Mb/s', '    Cisco extended id is unknown (0x0)', '    Cisco part number is 10-2195-01', '    Cisco pid is DS-SFP-FC4G-SW', '', '    No tx fault, no rx loss, in sync state, diagnostic monitoring type is 0x68', '    SFP Diagnostics Information:', '       Temperature           :  33.85 C    ', '        Voltage               :   3.30 V       ', '        Current               :   8.18 mA         ', '        Optical Tx Power      :  -4.05 dBm        ', '        Optical Rx Power      :  -2.87 dBm        ', '        Tx Fault count  : 0', '    Note: ++  high-alarm; +  high-warning; --  low-alarm; -low-warning', '', 'fc1/5 sfp is present', '    Name is CISCO-FINISAR', "    Manufacturer's part number is FTLF8524P2BNL-C2", '    Revision is D', '    Serial number is FNS19200WNK', '    Nominal bit rate is 4300 Mb/s', '    FC Transmitter type is short wave laser w/o OFC (SN)', '    FC Transmitter supports intermediate distance link length', '    Transmission medium is multimode laser with 62.5 um aperture (M6)', '    Supported speeds are - Min speed: 1000 Mb/s, Max speed: 4000 Mb/s', '    Cisco extended id is unknown (0x0)', '    Cisco part number is 10-2195-01', '    Cisco pid is DS-SFP-FC4G-SW', '', '    No tx fault, no rx loss, in sync state, diagnostic monitoring type is 0x68', '    SFP Diagnostics Information:', '       Temperature           :  27.45 C    ', '        Voltage               :   3.31 V       ', '        Current               :   7.30 mA         ', '        Optical Tx Power      :  -4.08 dBm        ', '        Optical Rx Power      :  -3.21 dBm        ', '        Tx Fault count  : 0', '    Note: ++  high-alarm; +  high-warning; --  low-alarm; -low-warning', '', 'fc1/6 sfp not present', 'fc1/7 sfp not present', 'fc1/8 sfp not present', 'fc1/9 sfp not present', 'fc1/10 sfp not present', 'fc1/11 sfp not present', 'fc1/12 sfp not present', 'fc1/13 sfp not present', 'fc1/14 sfp not present', 'fc1/15 sfp not present', 'fc1/16 sfp not present', 'fc1/17 sfp not present', 'fc1/18 sfp not present', 'fc1/19 sfp not present', 'fc1/20 sfp not present', 'fc1/21 sfp not present', 'fc1/22 sfp not present', 'fc1/23 sfp not present', 'fc1/24 sfp not present', 'fc1/25 sfp not present', 'fc1/26 sfp not present', 'fc1/27 sfp not present', 'fc1/28 sfp not present', 'fc1/29 sfp not present', 'fc1/30 sfp not present', 'fc1/31 sfp not present', 'fc1/32 sfp not present', 'fc1/33 sfp not present', 'fc1/34 sfp not present', 'fc1/35 sfp not present', 'fc1/36 sfp not present', 'fc1/37 sfp not present', 'fc1/38 sfp not present', 'fc1/39 sfp not present', 'fc1/40 sfp not present', 'fc1/41 sfp not present', 'fc1/42 sfp not present', 'fc1/43 sfp not present', 'fc1/44 sfp not present', 'fc1/45 sfp not present', 'fc1/46 sfp not present', 'fc1/47 sfp not present', 'fc1/48 sfp not present']

Comment: Please follow the instructions here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: All 5 datas -Name, manufacture's   part no, serial no  are to  be fetched from a   list and kept inside a dictionary.

Comment: I am   getting 'TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str' error